# Minikube: Kong ingress is ignored

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, minikube, kong

I try to run our applications on a local cluster to emulate the behaviour in the productive cluster. To get a cluster I installed Minikube as a Docker Container. Kong is installed as Minikube addon (`minikube addons enable kong`). The application is startet using Tilt, which creates the Kubernetes config files from a HelmChart.

Our applications needs a custom HTTP header to be set to extract the tenant. In our productive environment this is realized by reading the host from the request using a Kong plugin. **The problem is when trying to rebuild it using Tilt and Minikube, that the Kong ingress is not used.**

To emulate the DNS server I added `127.0.0.1 custom.local` to the Windows hosts file. The ingress.yml looks like this (names changed for better understanding):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    konghq.com/https-redirect-status-code: "301"
    konghq.com/plugins: iprestriction-plugin-namespace-imagename, header-plugin-namespace-imagename-tenant
    konghq.com/protocols: https
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"konghq.com/https-redirect-status-code":"301","konghq.com/plugins":"iprestriction-plugin-namespace-imagename, header-plugin-namespace-imagename-tenant","konghq.com/protocols":"https"},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"namespace","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"tilt","app.kubernetes.io/name":"imagename","app.kubernetes.io/version":"1.01.000","helm.sh/chart":"imagename-1.7.0"},"name":"namespace-imagename--custom-local--tenant","namespace":"namespace"},"spec":{"ingressClassName":"kong","rules":[{"host":"custom.local","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"service":{"name":"namespace-imagename","port":{"name":"http"}}},"path":"/","pathType":"Prefix"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["custom.local"],"secretName":"ssl-secret"}]}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-09-01T12:30:10Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: namespace
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: tilt
    app.kubernetes.io/name: imagename
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.01.000
    helm.sh/chart: imagename-1.7.0
  name: namespace-imagename--custom-local--tenant
  namespace: namespace
  resourceVersion: "112665"
  uid: 80c188ae-a952-4555-b446-12705f05e99b
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - host: custom.local
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: namespace-imagename
            port:
              name: http
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - custom.local
    secretName: ssl-secret
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

When I open `custom.local` in the browser, I arrive at the webpage from my application, however I get an error that the tenant header is not set. The log of the Kong Pod in Minikube stays empty, whereas in our productive environment the received requests are logged. It looks like the ingress is completely ignored.

As our HelmChart has the possibility to work with NGinx, I also tried using that ingress, but the result is the same. I also tried installing Kong from the official source using `kubectl`, same result. I also thought that maybe the IP-restriction is problematic, but turning it off had no effect either. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I got a new idea. In the Tiltfile the port 8080 of the pod is forwarded to the port 80 on my local machine. Hence the ingress cannot be used. To test if this is the main problem I just need to configure the Ingress controller to listen to my local port 80.